# Plastic/Elasticsearch - search for entries with null value

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 with https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic and have a table called job_ads. The job_ads table has a type column which sometimes is null. I want to search for all job_ads with a type of null but if I try

```
App\JobAd::search()->term('type', null)->sortBy("id", "ASC")->get()->totalHits();
```

via php artisan tinker I get

```
Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception with message 'query_parsing_exception: No value specified for term query'
```

I had a look at the elasticsearch documents but I don't see my mistake. I'm using elasticsearch 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-exists-query.html#_literal_missing_literal_query) inside must not clause. It is basically a [missing query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-missing-query.html)(Deprecated in 2.2.0) which looks for **null values**.Try following query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have not used *plastic* but It should be easy to convert. From the [documentation](https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic#bool-query) it should be something like following query

```
App\JobAd::search()->mustNot()->exists('type')->sortBy("id", "ASC")->get()->totalHits();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was just reading about the missing query, so I was on the right track :) Your code works, thanks!

Comment: glad I could help!